# Configure Yesod app as CGI

Tags: haskell, cgi, fastcgi, yesod

Given a freshly scaffolded Yesod application, what is the minimal set of changes necessary to get an executable which acts as a CGI program? A wrapper program is acceptable. If the default executable built by 'cabal build' is a CGI program, what environment variables must be set for it to act as a CGI (as by default it will bind to a port and attempt to serve requests there.)

A similar answer for FastCGI would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update your `app/main.hs` with the following:

```
import Prelude              (IO, (>>=))
import Yesod.Default.Config (fromArgs)
import Yesod.Default.Main   (defaultMain)
import Settings             (parseExtra)
import Application          (makeApplication)
import Network.Wai.Handler.CGI (run)

main :: IO ()
main = fromArgs parseExtra >>= makeApplication >>= run
```

You'll need to add `wai-extra` to the dependencies in your cabal file. To use FastCGI instead, replace `Network.Wai.Handler.CGI` with `Network.Wai.Handler.FastCGI` and add `wai-handler-fastcgi` to the dependency list instead.

Comment: Does this break 'yesod devel'?

Comment: Just to clarify why: the scaffolded site is built as a library which (essentially) provides an `IO Application`. Then there are two executables: `main.hs` is used for production and `devel.hs` is used for `yesod devel`. So the changes to `main.hs` have no effect on development.