# Yesod app deployment as CGI program

Tags: cgi, yesod

Already managed to create a Yesod application running in "yesod -d devel". After that, I modified as in article [Configure Yesod app as CGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107460/configure-yesod-app-as-cgi) (I'm restricted to CGI and won't have any of the development tools nor GHC on the production environment) and did a rebuild with

```
cabal-dev clean && cabal-dev configure && cabal-dev build
```

Calling the resulting binary by hand to simulate a CGI environment, I get the response:

```
Invalid environment, valid entries are: [Development,Testing,Staging,Production]
```

while --help gives me that:

```
Usage: yussuf <environment> [--port <port>]
Valid environments: [Development,Testing,Staging,Production]
```

When I pass "Production" as a first parameter, the following response occurs:

```
getAddrInfo: does not exist (Name or service not known)
```

So what am I doing wrong? Does the additional parameter mean that I'll need sort of a wrapper script to correctly call the application, or how to really get that to work?

Comment: After trying to solve things with moving forward to the recent Yesod version, straightly running into new problems with changed types. As I'm already late with presenting results I'll have to give up. Goodbye Haskell community, and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`getAddrInfo: does not exist (Name or service not known)` typically means that a DNS query failed.