# Serving a yesod application as a (Fast)CGI

Tags: apache, haskell, cgi, yesod, haskell-wai

I'm trying to serve a yesod application as a CGI (or FastCGI) program but Apache shows me a 500 error:

> [Mon Sep 21 17:35:41.425565 2020] [http:error] [pid 2758] [client 10.0.2.2:43872] AH02429: Response header name '21/Sep/2020' contains invalid characters, aborting request

Starting with a new template with `stack new project yesodweb/sqlite`, I've tried to convert it to a CGI program by changing `src/Application.hs`.

I've imported the Wai CGI library with

```
import Network.Wai.Handler.CGI              (run)
```

and changed the last line of `appMain` to `run app`:

```
-- | The @main@ function for an executable running this site.
appMain :: IO ()
appMain = do 
    -- Get the settings from all relevant sources
    settings <- loadYamlSettingsArgs
        -- fall back to compile-time values, set to [] to require values at runtime
        [configSettingsYmlValue]
 
        -- allow environment variables to override
        useEnv
 
    -- Generate the foundation from the settings
    foundation <- makeFoundation settings
 
    -- Generate a WAI Application from the foundation
    app <- makeApplication foundation
                                             
    -- Run the application with Warp
    --runSettings (warpSettings foundation) app
    run app
```

I thought this was the minimal change to serve it as a CGI program but apparently is not working.

I've already looked into yesod's book [chapter on deploying your Webapp](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/deploying-your-webapp) which has been handy to write the apropriate Apache configuration so the server could ran the app. It says nothing about the nedded changes to the app code which I presume is where the problem is.

I've also checked this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107460/configure-yesod-app-as-cgi) but it's from almost 8 years ago so it's outdated now.

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.yesodweb.com/book/deploying-your-webapp

Comment: Yes, I've already looked into it but I can't find anything useful there but the Apache configuration which, besides the rewriting rules, is the same as mine.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be either a problem with managing the restart of the program since the error is about response headers and in the first execution of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the default `makeFoundation` logs to standard output, which is also where the CGI program is supposed to send its response,  so you're getting intermingling of response headers with log output, and Apache tries to parse log lines as HTTP headers, etc.

If you replace `newStdoutLoggerSet` with `newStderrLoggerSet`, it should work, and the log output will end up in Apache's "error.log" or equivalent.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly the problem.